# New chain periodically rides the gear teeth

Tags: chain, cassette

I have a Dahon eezz D3 which I recently changed the chain. When I did the test riding, I felt that the pedal some how skipped or jump, more frequently on the lower gears (I believe that it happened periodically). As I checked the bike, I found that the cassette and the chain sometimes did not synchronize. The roller of the chain sometimes climbed up the gear tooth then jump down to the correct position between the two teeth, and this causes the skipping or jumping.

Has anyone experienced something like this and know how to solve it?

Please note that the condition of the cassette is still fine (3,000+ km), and the new chain was cut according to the number of joints of the old one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  How much wear did the chain have?  Did you change the cassette as well?  Very often a worn chain will cause wear on the cassette and you'll need to change both of them.

Comment: The chain is just new. The cassette is the old one I use it for 2+ years, for about 3,000+ km. Don't you think it is too early to change the cassette? It looks quite ok to my eyes.

Comment: Is it the correct chain, too? The [description](https://eu.dahon.com/bikes/eezz-d3/) says "3-Speed DAHON Rear Tiagra Derailleur", so I assume this means 10-speed super-narrow, as [suggested](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tiagra-4700/CN-HG54.html) by Shimano.

Comment: The chain I bought is from decathlon. it says for 3-8 speed.

Comment: Well, then you could have the wrong chain. 8- and 10-speed a different chain widths and Tiagra was introduced with 9-speed as far as I know (newer iterations are 10-speed), so you probably need to get a CN-HG54 10-speed chain, instead? I'm not sure how Dahon has implemented 3-speed with Tiagra, but I guess it is just regular components with limited gear range,  for example a shifter with only three clicks? In case of doubt, ask a LBS with your old chain or contact Dahon...

Comment: If the number of speed don't match, it's indeed the first possibility to check. For reference 3000km could be enough to wear a cassette if the previous chain was worn beyond the infamous 1% limit: worn chains accelerate cassette wear - but on a bike used mainly on the road, that should imply basically no chain maintenance at all, and riding in hard condition (dust, rain or mud).

Comment: Unless you are able to get the same type of chain OR know what specs you should have gotten you are left with having to measure the width yourself. Your bike seems to have some non standard freewheel so assuming things quickly takes you down the wrong path.

Comment: Any news from the chain department? Did you figure out what chain your bike needs? 8-speed is wider than newer generations and the links could easily catch the next cog's tooth and do all sorts of jumping and skipping, could fit the symptoms...

Comment: I have not done anything yet, but I have measure the outer widths of the chain the new one is about 0.7 mm, but the old one is about 0.6 mm. I also double check the cause of the jumping which still them same cause as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DoNuT After a long observation I finally solved the problem, please see below in the comment of the correct answer. Thank you for your advice about the size of the chain, it is very helpful.

Comment: @fronthem OK interesting that it was just the B-screw. Did you figure out what kind of chain should actually go on your bike? I'm not sure what you measured but bikes are usually pretty delicate about [chain dimensions](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/3555/bicycle-drive-chain-dimension-standards/#3) - between 8 and 10-speed there's more than 1 mm difference, as an example, on my 11-speed bike, there's hardly any clearance between outer plate and cogs, so fitting a 9/10-speed chain and it would definitely hit the next cog all the time and do all sorts of silly things other than running straight.

Comment: @DoNuT I believed that the derailleur I have was Shimano Tiagra, but it was not. My derailleur has the Dahon marker on it which I found that it exactly the same as LTWOO FW3 the Chinese brand. Anyway, It works fine and 9 speed chain fit well in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilties here -

1. Chains and cassettes wear in together.  And a worn cassette looks very much like an unworn cassette.   If you DON'T get the skip when in gears that you don't use much, but do get skips in your preferred gears, then its likely a worn cassette.
2. Chains have a length.  As-sold they are often overly-long, and this means less chain tension.  Ideally the new chain should be trimmed to the same number of links as the old chain, which is not necessarily the same as the length.  SO lay the new and old chains side by side on the ground and line up the links before trimming.

Comment: You are right what happened to my bike was about the the worn cassette. Another thing that made it worse is the space between the rear sprocket of the derailleur sprocket (the one closest to the hub). I set the B-screw to the lowest level to reduce this space which made the angle of the chain between the two sprockets adjusted more horizontally. This horizon angle of the chain made its rollers move toward the side of the cog teeth rather than the top of the teeth (which make it stuck at the first place). Problem solved for me! Thanks for you answer.